# Are there any tutorials for configuring Jenkins with the Force.com Migration Tool?

Tags: force.com, continuous-integration, migration-tool, jenkins

I have watched a couple of interesting videos from Dreamforce about using Jenkins for Continuous integration, none of them go into the details of configuring Ant withForce.com Migration Tool in Jenkins. I haven't had any luck searching for this. Does anyone any guide/tutorial or can provide some steps to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know of one to link to for you.  I'm not near Jenkins right now, but I think the following is basically accurate.

1. Follow the [directions here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_deploying_ant.htm) to make sure that you have java, ant and the ant-salesforce.jar downloaded and installed or avaiable.
2. [Install Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins) ([these instructions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins#MeetJenkins-Installation) may be easier for you on Windows).
3. Get Jenkins [running](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) (different depending on how you installed).  *You may have already done this as part of step #2.*
4. Create your [Jenkins project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) and configure an [Ant task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-AntScripts).
5. Once you have your project set up you can run your job on demand until you get it to succeed and view the console output to verify that it is working.  Then you can schedule it to run periodically such as every night at midnight or poll your source code repository.

Honestly, I put a lot of links in here that have detailed instructions, but it is not difficult to get Jenkins up and running and once you have it up and running the GUI is very intuitive and you can figure most of it out yourself. The directions [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins#MeetJenkins-Installation) are pretty straightforward and you can even [test drive it](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins#MeetJenkins-TestDrive).

The Salesforce [Using the Force.com Migration Tool doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_deploying_ant.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_deploying_ant.htm|SkinName=webhelp) has good samples of ant build files that cover different deployment scenarios.

Comment: I was able to get it working..to some extent.. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 7):

We just got done building our CI infrastructure around the next release of the Nonprofit Starter Pack at the Salesforce.com Foundation.  We open sourced all the documentation including the Jenkins configurations and scripts used as well as a custom webapp (mrbelvedere) we deploy on Heroku and use for some custom logic not possible directly in Jenkins:

Documentation:
http://salesforcefoundation.github.io/CumulusCI/

mrbelvedere:
https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/mrbelvedere

I did an hour long webinar a few weeks ago on the setup as well which was recorded:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cm42ZF5MrLA

Comment: In case someone references this older answer, these two videos are the best current documentation around CumulusCI in addition to the commit history in the CumulusCI repository:  http://dreamforce.vidyard.com/watch/9qWCaabFMQY4G1yeUHJyCw http://dreamforce.vidyard.com/watch/qWZdC_n0I8OagLzg_RJmIA

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Amazon AMI I have associated with this [github repo](https://github.com/BracketLabs/AppExchange-Team-Development-on-Force.com-Platform-Demo#using-the-ami), it's preconfigured with ANT Migration tool, and Jenkins ready to go.

I can also answer any questions about the instructions there.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I searched for the AMI under the Community AMIs section as per the instructions but it's not listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide how to setup Jenkins on AWS and then connect it to a GitHub repository and to build the repository on Salesforce
http://www.pexlify.com/setting-up-jenkins-on-aws-as-a-ci-server-for-salesforce/

Comment: Or, while is possible that the link gives the proper answer, links can (and often do) go dead. Can you please extract the salient points of the article and add them to your answer so others can benefit? (Don't remove the link, though)