# Force.com IDE auto-commit on deploy

Tags: migration-tool, eclipse

We are using the standard SVN eclipse plugin: `Subversion`.

Is it possible to configure Force.com IDE to **auto launch** the SVN **commit after "*deploy to server*" ?**

I was looking for something like "hooks" options on Force.com options without success.

*Idea*:
Could be possible to use a bash script combining ant (migration tool) and svn commit and finally add this bash command as a eclipse button?

Comment: Typically I see this done the other way around.  Deploy upon commit.  I use continuous integration with Jenkins and Phabricator and its pretty sweet.  See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3559/are-there-any-tutorials-for-configuring-jenkins-with-the-force-com-migration-too

Comment: Thanks Phil, It seems to be a good other approach. I'll try it.